# card over the end of a div

Tags: css, flexbox

Hello i searched and found nothing about i would like to put cards on the end of a div like this:

[image]

I imagine what would have to do with position absolute and relative but I can't imagine how to put the two divs

code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <div className="Header" />
      <div className="Content">
        <div className="Carousel" />
        <div className="main" />
      </div>
      <div className="footer">a</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.Header {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  flex: none;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
.Content {
  flex: 1;
}
.Carousel {
  background: #1976d2;
  background-image: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/nottingham-park.png);
  flex: none;
  height: 280px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  padding-top: 128px !important;
  padding-bottom: 128px !important;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
}
.main {
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 0.625em;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  max-width: 97.2307692rem !important;
}

.footer {
  max-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  flex: none;
}
```

example on codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-mestorf-6kmmo

Comment: I don't see an attempt on your part here -- there are no cards in the sandbox. You either need to use a negative margin, a transform to move them down like that. Please, make an attempt and put that new code into your question, otherwise it is likely to get closed.

Comment: I didn't try it because I didn't really find anything I know I have to put a div with absolute position, but my question is exactly how I will be able to put it at the end of a div and at the beginning of another centralized one.

Comment: As I stated, you do it with either negative top margins or by using the transform property with a `translateY` function. Both of those things are things I trust you can look up.

Comment: ok so basically i need 3 divs
one with negative margin and position absolute
?

and two with position relative

Comment: Absolute positioning is another way, but people tend to avoid it for reasons that I'm struggling to recall now (think it has something to do with transform performing largely the same, in a simpler manner). Basically you would add the elements to whichever of those two elements, and then you use the transform function to nudge them up (if housed in the yellow portion) or down (if housed in the blue portion).

Comment: I managed to create now thanks https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-mestorf-6kmmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add inside your code 3 cards:

```
<div className="Container">
  <div className="Header" />
  <div className="Content">
    <div className="Carousel" />
    <div className="cardContainer">
      <div className="card">Card 1</div>
      <div className="card">Card 2</div>
      <div className="card">Card 3</div>
    </div>
    <div className="main" />
  </div>
  <div className="footer">a</div>
</div>
```

And then use css to adjust them:

- cardContainer height should be set to 0 to avoid spacing between the other divs
- negative margin-top could be applied to cardContainer or single divs to place them "on the end of a div"
- z-index could be required to prevent them from going under the div
- display flex and justify-content are used to place 3 div equally spaced.

CSS

```
.cardContainer {
  height: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: -150px;
}

.cardContainer div {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 100px 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hi bro thanks for help, Could you look at this example that I just made and tell me which one would be more correct to use? codesandbox.io/s/angry-mestorf-6kmmo

Comment: Using translateY is another working way to reach your result.
I often use negative margin but the method you used does almost exactly the same job.
I personally wouldn't use inline css and margin-right in single boxes, use flexboxes and it would be so much easier to add an element in the future!
You can find a very good guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Make a Div with your cards and position it absolutely between the two sections. I put it inside the first section.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: green;
}

section:last-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.card {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">Card 1</div>
      <div class="card">Card 2</div>
      <div class="card">Card 3</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: hi bro thanks for help, Could you look at this example that I just made and tell me which one would be more correct to use?
  https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-mestorf-6kmmo

Answer (score 0):

With the tips from @Jhecht

code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <div className="Header" />
      <div className="Content">
        <div className="Carousel" />
        <div className="main">
          <div
            className="card"
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              background: "transparent",
              height: "200px"
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                height: "400px",
                marginRight: "10px",
                background: "green",
                width: "350px"
              }}
            />
            <div
              style={{
                height: "400px",
                marginRight: "10px",
                background: "black",
                width: "350px"
              }}
            />
            <div
              style={{ height: "400px", background: "green", width: "350px" }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="footer">a</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.Header {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  flex: none;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
.Content {
  flex: 1;
}
.Carousel {
  position: relative;
  background: #1976d2;
  background-image: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/nottingham-park.png);
  flex: none;
  height: 280px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  padding-top: 128px !important;
  padding-bottom: 128px !important;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
}
.main {
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 0.625em;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  max-width: 97.2307692rem !important;
}

.footer {
  max-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  flex: none;
}

.card {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```